# JSONDecodeError opening a text file in Python with multiple lines

Tags: python, json, text

I am attempting to open a text file pulled from hdfs, extract certain values, and output this file into a single row csv file. Below is the 'content' of the text file and the code I am using to extract the data and output:

```
#file.txt
{"timestamp": someInt, "videoId": someString, "overridden": someInt, "scores": [{"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}]}

{"timestamp": someInt, "videoId": someString, "overridden": someInt, "scores": [{"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}, {"bucket": someString, "name": someString, "value": someInt}]}

...
```

The initial code:

```
wanted_data = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    json_data = json.loads(line)
    wanted_data.append(json_data['videoId'])
    for i in range(6):
      wanted_data.append(json_data['scores'][i]['bucket'])
      wanted_data.append(json_data['scores'][i]['value'])

with open('file.csv', 'w+') as f_out:
  write = csv.writer(f_out)
  write.writerow(wanted_data)
```

Which results in a JSONDecode Error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

What is the proper way I should be loading this text file?

Comment: it looks  like you have empty lines between actual json strings. check `if line.strip():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have empty lines between JSON strings. check that line actually has some text before processing it:

```
wanted_data = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.strip():
      json_data = json.loads(line)
      wanted_data.append(json_data['videoId'])
      for score in json_data['scores']:
        wanted_data.append(score['bucket'])
        wanted_data.append(score['value'])
```

Comment: Woah, that did it! Thank you so much :) I can't believe I missed that.